# How to auto re-size the bootstrap column width based on data inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have 3 divs inside my row class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">some content</div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="col-6">conetnt</div>
          <div class="col-6">conetnt</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8"> content </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify this **`HTML`** so that, all the content inside floats right and auto adjust its width based on the content? Now the width is fixed, so even if the data in my 3rd div very little it still consumes loads of space. Any idea guys? bit newbie to CSS

Comment: I want to float my entire content inside second div in to right and stick with the third div left side

Comment: hey why dont you use col-md-1 if you want less space

Comment: and if you want it should take the width as much as the content just use a div not any bootstrap class and apply ```float:left``` to the parent div

Comment: Your code dont work because of wrong classes. You are missing the viewport prefix for bootstrap-column classes (e.g. .col-md-1): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: bootstrap grid classes are used as ```col-md-12``` not as ```col-12``` you are using wrong classes

Comment: Am using Angular 2. col-12 also working

Comment: May be its useful try to : col-md-auto

Answer (score 3):

**Solution :**

If your content is occupying space less than width of your bootstrap column. You better put it without bootstrap column classes and give it simply **float:left** to your content inside the simple div.

It will automatically be resized according to your content. You may need to give **display:inline** to your div to display that div inline.

**Update :**
You can use flexbox. **display: flex** to container and can use **flex-direction** attribute according to your need.

**Reference :**

First you need to study the behavior of bootstrap grid systems. This official bootstrap documentation is all about **grid system** of bootstrap (Latest version).

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

It will help you to understand **content management inside bootstrap rows and columns.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use float: right to move content on right and try using display: table

Have a look here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: hey he has not used correct class and even he is not specific...he needs to read the documentation of the bootstrap